# Django: How can I get a joined table from Child model?

Tags: django, django-models

I created OneToOneField in the child model, Return Rate, and tried to get a joined table based the child table using `select_related()` method.
However the result queryset doesn't show the joined result, but only the child data.

Models.py:

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class ReturnRate(models.Model):
    ticker = models.OneToOneField(Coin, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    to_field='ticker', related_name='tick')
```

Views.py:

```
def get(request):
    models.ReturnRate.objects.selected_related('ticker')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what does it mean by joined result, you have only one value field in `ReturnRate`. you are getting data for that. if you want `id` also you can access that by .id or following.
selected_related('ticker')

```
models.ReturnRate.objects.values(
    'id', 'ticker__name', 'ticker__ticker')
```